# Execute script when upload via FTP

Tags: file-upload, ftp

I was simply wondering if it was possible to execute a PHP script when the webmaster uploads a file (image in this case) in a certain folder from a FTP software?

If yes, what methods would work best? Any link/resource/tip is glady appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no event triggered when a user uploads a file trough FTP, but what you can do is use cron to run a script every 5 minutes, the script will scan the upload folder and perform an action on the new files found.

Comment: I thought it would be possible by adding/modifying some .ini/.batch file on the server. Thanks anyways.